# how to protect access to my company website to only employees

Tags: php, mysql

i have made a company website which has the MYSQL database of accounting,inventory,expenses, etc. now i want only company employees to be able to access the website . for example, managers will get access to specific pages, data entry operator for specific, sales persons for specific pages, and so on.
i want the username/passwords, etc. to be stored on mysql securely with strong security on the website.
i am quite clueless as to how to implement this on the website. i would greatly appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common approach is to have two tables, one with users and one with roles assigned to those users (as one user can have multiple roles). In your example, roles could be 'manager', 'data entry', 'sales' etc.

Create a login page, with form with fields for username and password. On form submission, check if provided credentials are valid (by executing a query), and if so, store user data in current session. On start of every secured page, retrieve that data from session, and check if user has sufficient priviledges to access the page (for example, has the right role). If yes, render the page; if not, render some kind of error.

If your website is public, you should worry about possible attacks against it. Securing the website can be pretty difficult. You can start by reading about some common attacks and ways to deal with them here: http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/

In general, security is hard, and I think the best approach would be to use some ready-made framework. You can find a list of such frameworks here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP_frameworks#PHP_2 . If your website is already made, though, it may be a little late for that, as they tend to be quite heavyweight. Maybe PEAR::Auth (http://pear.php.net/package/Auth) will help you?

Comment: thanks @socha23 can you please refer me somewhere for the ready made framework of this kind. i have looked up and there are a lot of membership softwares but that is for maintaining a huge member base. all i want is to maintain about 100 users but they will be accessing from different places, so i need to have the website online.thanks

Answer (score 1):

On way is, Map user Name with EmployeeID and EmployeeID shall be mapped with Role. So while logging in, write the code to Hide/Show the pages according to the Employee Role who logged in.

Comment: hi @Mohanavel i have added the userid's to the employees table.but what do i add the roles based on, should i add it page wise, if yes, then do i need to mention the page title in a separate table with user id and page title? and then after that what do i need to do

Comment: This is bit Hard to Explain, i try my best. One approach is, you can have structure like this. Employee table should have RoleID(without Map Table) or RolesID(through Map Table) which will point to Role Table. Role Table should have PageMapID(may have Privileged) and point to PageMapID. PageMap table should have PageMapId and PageID, this PageID will point to Page Table. I guess this will give some idea.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking about involves many, many different aspects which you need to think about, and is kinda hard to explain in a single answer.

In brief:
Make a users table. This table will have userID's, names etc. and also a field for privilege level, which can be an array of all the areas the user is allowed to access. Read up on how to store user data, like hashing passwords etc.

You will have to create a session at log-in, and check the session to see if the currently logged in user is allowed to see the page each time a new page is loaded up. Look into basic php session handling, and cookies etc.

Now making all this secure is going to take a lot of reading up on building secure webapps. For starters, you'd want to be using prepared statements for your SQL queries to prevent injection attacks, use ssl for logging in so that user data can't be intercepted etc etc.

You can prevent most security risks, assuming nobody IN the company wants to compromise the system, by hosting it locally in your office and allowing access only to the local network/VPN or something. Unless, of course, you need it accessible online.